# Jest, ts-jest, typescript with ES Modules import : cannot find module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have hard time getting jest to work with typescript project that use ES modules with `import` syntax.
My project was initially written for commonjs, jest test run fine. But then I decided to switch to ES Modules(for learning purpose), jest is not happy ヽ(`Д´)ﾉ
The tools that I am using: **typescript, jest, ts-jest**

The issue start with `import` syntax.

The following are codes that I had tried.

```
//  projectRoot/src/app.ts

export default someFunction = (): void => {
   // some code
}
```

If

```
// projectRoot/__tests__/app.test.ts

import someFunction from '../src/app';   // without file extension

/* This execute perfectly fine */
```

But

```
// projectRoot/__tests__/app.test.ts

import someFunction from '../src/app.ts'   // with .ts

/*
● Test suite failed to run

   __tests__/app.test.ts:1:25 - error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing '../src/app' instead.

    1 import information from '../src/app.ts';
*/
```

And

```
// projectRoot/__tests__/app.test.ts

import someFunction from '../src/app.js';   // with .js

/*
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '../src/app.js' from '__tests__/app.test.ts'
*/
```

As above example, jest(or maybe ts-jest?) is not happy if I import the module with extension(which is a must for ES Modules).
I did some searching online, but seem like jest [doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules) is not very supportive for ES Modules. Same goes to ts-jest by this [reading](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1709)

My Project structure:

```
/projectRoot
 ├── /src/app.ts
 ├── /__tests__/app.test.ts
```

Inside package.json file has value `"type": "module"`

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "ES2015",
     "module": "ESNEXT",
     "outDir": "./build",
     "strict": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

jest.config.js

```
export default {
    "roots": [
      //"<rootDir>/src"
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": 'node'
  }
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a link to a github repo or sth?

Comment: Hi @geodoo, here is my repo [https://github.com/koonfoon/ts-jest-code-test](https://github.com/koonfoon/ts-jest-code-test)

Comment: Did anyone solve this problem?

Comment: @Rafael please see my answer below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With the import below

```
// projectRoot/__tests__/app.test.ts

import someFunction from '../src/app.js';   // with .js
```

ts-jest can be configured to use this with the following configurations. In **jest.config.js** file, add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  //... // your previous configurations
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      //... // your other configurations here
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  }
```

The source of this configuration can be found on ts-jest's documentation page: [ESM-Support](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support)

Some of my sample code is below:

```
// components_ts.ts
export add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}
```

```
// render_ts.ts
import * as ComponentsTS from './components_ts.js'; // <-- Extension is JS

export function addedNumbers(): number {
    let addedNumbers: number = ComponentsTS.add(1, 2);
    return addedNumbers;
}
```

```
// render_ts.test.ts
import * as RenderTS from '../ts_files/render_ts';

it ('Test addNumbers function', () => {
    expect(RenderTS.addedNumbers()).toBe(3);
});
```

Run this with `npm jest`

Comment: moduleNameMapper is what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: This is a great answer. I configured `moduleNameMapper` as '^(\\.{1,2}/.+)\\.js$': '$1', which uses + instead of *

Comment: Thanks for this! I was driving nuts. Adding `moduleNameMapper` did the trick for me as well.